# Does AS3 wait for each line of code in a function to be executed before moving on to the next line?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to dispatch an event but not sure when I should do it to get the right results. The first event "submitClicked" is in the right spot and works great. However, the second event "dataReady" seems like it might be a problem.

I need it to be dispatched after this.compiledFormData is set.
Does AS3 wait for each line of code in a function to be executed before moving on to the next line?

```
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function submitForm()
    {   
        //dispatch an event
        var cEvt:FormRendererEvent = new FormRendererEvent( "submitClicked" );
        cEvt.customMessage = "Started Submitting Form Data";
        dispatchEvent(cEvt);

        this.compiledFormData = JSON.encode(this.compileFormData());

        var cEvt:FormRendererEvent = new FormRendererEvent( "dataReady" );
        cEvt.customMessage = "Data is ready to be used";
        dispatchEvent(cEvt);

    }//end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in AS3 each line must complete before the next line can run. When you dispatch events though, they will go off and do their own thing. So, your "main" code might complete, meanwhile your dispatched events could still be processing.

Comment: So... within a function the code runs in order waiting on each line to finish before moving on to the next line. But when you dispatch an event in the middle of a function it will continue to run the current function like normal and start running any functions associated with the dispatched event at the same time. Is that correct? So you could have two or more functions being executed at the same time?

Comment: Yes, any number of events could be processed in the background. @Marplesoft was right in that the line, 'this.compiledFormData = ....' will run synchronously, while your dispatched events will run asynchronously in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Each line of code is executed sequentially yes, but whether the implementation of the invoked API does something asynchronous is dependent on what API you're calling.

In this case `JSON.encode` is a synchronous operation and therefore will complete fully before the next line of code is executed.

Comment: How can you determine if it is synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: When JSON.encode runs it is considered synchronous. But if that function dispatched an event then it would be considered asynchronous, correct? However, JSON.encode being synchronous or asynchronous shouldn't affect the code that I posted above, correct?

Comment: In a general sense, it depends on the method. In your example, you are correct. But you really need to read the docs.